# React: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4

I am a newbie when it comes to react and webpack4 and doesn't have much experience with Javascript either.

I get the follwing error when I run `npm run dev` (see package.json further down):

```
ERROR in ./project/frontend/src/components/App.js 6:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import Table from "./Table";
| const App = () => (
>   <DataProvider endpoint="api/lead/" render={data => <Table data={data} />} />
| );
| const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
 @ ./project/frontend/src/index.js 1:0-35
```

Package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "django-drf-react-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./project/frontend/src/index.js --output ./project/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./project/frontend/src/index.js --output ./project/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "weak-key": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/tutorial-api-django-rest-react/#Django_REST_with_React_requirements.

EDIT:
My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Table from "./Table";
const App = () => (
  <DataProvider endpoint="api/lead/" render={data => <Table data={data} />} />
);
const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : null;
```

SOLUTION:
Now it works. I played around with some  @Reema Parakh's suggstions in the comments and got new error, so pressed CRTL-Z until everything was back to normal, and now it works. I don't now why.

Comment: In your `webpack.config.js` file, in rules array, try adding this: `query: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
        }`

Comment: can you show how does your `webpack config` look like?

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error, what fixed it for me was putting `.babelrc` and `webpack.config.js` into the same folder as `package.json`. I was following the tutorial and it said put these in the "project folder" - in this case the top level folder and not the folder named `project`!

Answer (score 0):

Put your `webpack.config.js` in the same folder as `package.json` and if it doesn't solves the problem then go ahead delete `node_modules` and run the command `npm install` .It will reinstall the `node_modules` and hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score -5):

Together with an appropriate loader you basically need to import React to this file

```
import React from 'react'
```

This way it would its okay to have jsx format in this file
Also your code snippet doesn't contain DataProvider imported, so I think that is necessary to import into this file as well